# Google Chrome and Firefox cannot connect when Internet Explorer can

Tags: internet-connection, browser

I am trying to connect to the Internet from home with company laptop. Internet Explorer can connect fine. But Google Chrome and Firefox cannot.

Google Chrome displays error message "Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)".
And Firefox says "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

I suspect that my company did setup some restrictions on the browser to be used. Though Google Chrome and Firefox work at the office; so the problem is only from home.

Is there any way to find out what "blocks" the connection for the browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should speak to your IT department, they will know if it's set up this way intentionally or if it's a glitch.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably some security software product.

Just look at Control Panel / Programs and Features, and google the products you don't recognize, in order to find the guilty product.

Answer (score 1):

I would try different protocols (ping, ftp, https, mail, jabber, irc, and so on).

It doesn't sound like a proxy-setting. On work, all 3 browsers work, but at home, just IE?

How do you use the internet in the office (eth?, WLAN?) and at home?

Comment: In the office Internet works via Ethernet LAN. At home I have WLAN, then ADSL.

Comment: On windows, there is a menu entry/icon for System:Services:Messages - maybe you'll find more details there. I rarely use windows and have a localized version, where the name is 'System:Dienste' afaik, with logentries for system/network/application if I remember right. I can not control where exactly. It is close to other system configuration stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Entering `netsh winsock reset` in a Command Prompt window and rebooting is one solution I have seen.

That didn't work for me, but with Firefox 4.0 I had this issue, downloaded an update and things appeared to work again.